# How to distribute Eclipse Update Site

Tags: eclipse, github, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, bitbucket

I can't find a free repository allowing to distribute Eclipse Update Site. 
The main requirement is that it should provide access to raw content so that Eclipse can use the URL to retrieve all the binaries of my projects. 
GitHub provided access to raw url but it seems it stopped. 
Do you know if bitbucket does it? any different solution?

Comment: it still works on github. Example: http://mbarbero.github.io/fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform/p2/

Comment: I see, you use the gh-pages branch to host it thank you! (Acceleo rules)

Comment: Doesn't that work for your case?

Comment: Hi aphex I've tried it and no, it doesn't work.  I have a working gh-pages with an index.html in the root (it works). I have therefore added a folder containing the update site but, when I try to reach that folder I get a 404 error in the browser and a "could not find.." error in the Eclipse update manager

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Github also allows this. You need to create github page and upload your p2 repository there. On the website [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) is explained how to achieve that. Just scroll and the steps will appear on the page (fancy javascript). For your project there is a second repository, where you have to put your repository.

Comment: Hi aphex I've tried it and no, it doesn't work.  I have a working gh-pages with an index.html in the root (it works). I have therefore added a folder containing the update site but, when I try to reach that folder I get a 404 error in the browser and a "could not find.." error in the Eclipse update mangaer

Comment: I'll try it out tonight and let you know.

Comment: That would be very kind of you. It works if I push the update site contents in the gh-pages root but it doesn't if a push them inside a folder like you did with the 'p2' folder.

Comment: What was the problem? Unfortunately I didn't tested it yesterday.

Comment: here is the project I was aimed at distributing http://www.iubeo.org I am looking for contributors would you be interested ?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you *can* host an eclipse update site easily on github using raw url. I know because I have done it recently and it works.

It is true that you get a 404 when you try to access the repos 'raw' directory. However, that is actually not a problem because when you use the Eclipse (or Marketplace) installer to install something from an update site the installer does not access the folder directly. Rather it will only access *files* like 'catalog.xml'. This means that if you point the Eclipse installer at your raw update-site folder then it will be able to read the contents of the site without any problem.

Here is an example:

https://github.com/kdvolder/thirdparty-p2-repo/tree/4bb37ca4de6cd001f400c2913421b8c4b49538e1/target/repository

The corresponding raw url is this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kdvolder/thirdparty-p2-repo/4bb37ca4de6cd001f400c2913421b8c4b49538e1/target/repository

Yes, that will give a 404 when you click it. But that is okay, just open "Help >> Install New Software" and paste the link into the "Work with" field of the dialog and it works fine:

[image: screenshot of installer]

It works because raw urls like this one are all the installer needs:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kdvolder/thirdparty-p2-repo/4bb37ca4de6cd001f400c2913421b8c4b49538e1/target/repository/category.xml

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use sourceforge for the update site of my Eclipse projects.  I recently published a blog post detailing all the steps to achieve that http://www.lorenzobettini.it/2015/01/publish-an-eclipse-p2-repository-on-sourceforge-with-rsync/